# SBT package scala script

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to use spark submit with a scala script, but first I need to create my package.

Here is my sbt file:

```
name := "Simple Project"    
version := "1.0"    
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"    
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.0.0"
```

When I try **sbt package**, I am getting these errors:

```
/home/i329537/Scripts/PandI/SBT/src/main/scala/XML_Script_SBT.scala:3: object functions is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
                            ^
/home/i329537/Scripts/PandI/SBT/src/main/scala/XML_Script_SBT.scala:4: object types is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
                            ^
/home/i329537/Scripts/PandI/SBT/src/main/scala/XML_Script_SBT.scala:25: not found: value sc
        val hconf = SparkHadoopUtil.get.newConfiguration(sc.getConf)
                                                         ^
/home/i329537/Scripts/PandI/SBT/src/main/scala/XML_Script_SBT.scala:30: not found: value sqlContext
        val df = sqlContext.read.format("xml").option("attributePrefix","").option("rowTag", "project").load(uri.toString())
                 ^
/home/i329537/Scripts/PandI/SBT/src/main/scala/XML_Script_SBT.scala:36: not found: value udf
        val sqlfunc = udf(coder)
                      ^
5 errors found
(compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Is anyone faced these errors?

Thanks for helping.

Regards
Majid

Comment: Well, the first two are saying you are missing a SparkSQL packages. The later ones are saying you haven't declared some variables. Are you using an IDE to write your code?

Comment: Also, make sure that both your spark dependencies are synchronized in respect to their version.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am not using  any IDE. I solved the issue with SparkSQL packages by updating the spark depenencies, thanks to Sergey Kozyr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use class `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` and package `org.apache.spark.sql.types`. According to [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) class documentation it's available starting from version 1.3.0. And `types` package is available since version 1.3.1.

**Solution:** update SBT file to:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.3.1"`

Other errors: "not found: value sc", "not found: value sqlContext", "not found: value udf" are caused by some missing varibales in your `XML_Script_SBT.scala` file. Can't solve without looking into source code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sergey, your correction corrects 3 errors. Below is my script:

```
object SimpleApp {


  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val today = Calendar.getInstance.getTime
    val curTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")
    val time = curTimeFormat.format(today)
    val destination = "/3.Data/3.Code_Check_Processed/2.XML/" + time + ".extensive.csv"

    val source =  "/3.Data/2.Code_Check_Raw/2.XML/Extensive/"

    val hconf = SparkHadoopUtil.get.newConfiguration(sc.getConf)
    val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hconf)
    val iter = hdfs.listLocatedStatus(new Path(source))

    val uri = iter.next.getPath.toUri
    val df = sqlContext.read.format("xml").option("attributePrefix","").option("rowTag", "project").load(uri.toString())

    val df2 = df.selectExpr("explode(check) as e").select("e.#VALUE","e.additionalInformation1","e.columnNumber","e.context","e.errorType","e.filePath","e.lineNumber","e.message","e.severity")

    val coder: (Long => String) = (arg: Long) => {if (arg > -1) time else "nada"}

    val sqlfunc = udf(coder)

    val df3 = df2.withColumn("TimeStamp", sqlfunc(col("columnNumber")))

    df3.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").save(destination)

    hdfs.delete(new Path(uri.toString()), true)

    sys.exit(0)
     }
    }
```